# Does an irreducible representation in positive characteristic correspond to an irreducible one over other fields also?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Sorry if my question is too basic. I have just started learning about modular representation theory. suppose I know an irreducible representation of G over K where $char(K) = 2$ divides $|G|.$

Now let $F$ be a field such that $char(F) \nmid |G|.$ Then when can we say that the "same" V will be an irreducible representation of G over F. Any hint or reference suggestion would be highly appreciated.

What I know a bit is only the other way round. That a complex irreducible representation of G gives information about representations of G over F, when FG is semisimple. But I have no idea what happens in opposite direction.

Comment: As an example, let $G=GL_n(k)$, where $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic $p$, which obviously has an $n$-dimensional representation over $k$. Then $G$ has no finite-dimensional representations over $\mathbb C$. This is because the minimal dimension of a non-trivial irreducible representation of $GL_n(q)$ grows as $q$ grows.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks for your answer. But for some G it might be true. For example the article https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/8/ocr-ajc-v8-p45.pdf says that $A_7$ has an irreducible representation of degree 15 over $F_2.$ How can we check the same would work for any F, with $char(F) \ \nmid \ |G|?$

Comment: It is in general an incredibly difficult problem to decide if an irreducible representation in characteristic $0$ remains irreducible in characteristic $p$, whenever $p\mid |G|$. Solutions are known for individual groups, for example, the symmetric groups, and there are general criteria, for example if the degree of the representation is divisible by the order of the Sylow $p$-subgroup. But in general there is no neat answer.

Comment: Ok. Are there some similar general criteria for going other way round, e.g. going from char(K) = p dividing $|G|$ to char 0? For example, like I just said suppose I know a modular irreducible representation of A_n and want to see if it remains so in semisimple case too. Thanks in advance

Comment: In general if you have a representation in characteristic p there is no reason to expect that it lifts to characteristic zero -- for example it is quite possible for characteristic p representations to have dimension much smaller than any non-trivial characteristic zero representation.  However if you have an irreducible representation in characteristic p which for some reason you happen to know lifts to a representation in characteristic 0, then that lift is automatically irreducible.

Comment: Ok. Where can I study the lifting of representation? Actually I am just aware of complex representations.